# Linq Expression to Turn DataTable to Dictionary of <Key, List<Values>>

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to convert a DataTable of the form

```
Key  Value
1    A
1    B
1    C
2    X
2    Y
```

To a Dictionary

```
1 [A,B,C]
2 [X,Y]
```

The lambda expression I am using is

```
GetTable("..sql..").AsEnumerable().
    .Select(r => new {Key = r.Field<int>("Key"), Val = r.Field<string>("Value")})
    .GroupBy(g => g.Key)
    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => String.Join(",", a.Value))
```

But it fails with "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer' because it is not a delegate type"

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

This does it:

```
GetTable("..sql..").AsEnumerable().
    .Select(r => new {Key = r.Field<int>("Key"), Val = r.Field<string>("Value")})
    .GroupBy(g => g.Key)
    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => String.Join(",", a.Select(x => x.Value).ToList()))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way you can do it...

```
GetTable("..sql..").AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("Key"))
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, x => x.Select(y => y.Field<string>("Value")).ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var foo = GetTable("").AsEnumerable()
                 .ToLookup(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
foreach(var x in foo)
{
    foreach(var value in x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", x.Key, value));
    }

}
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I was after, but ToLookup is **really** useful - thanks.