# Convert DataTable into a Dictionary using Linq/Lambda

Tags: c#, dictionary, lambda

I have a DataTable that I would like to convert into dictionary in C# for my project. I can use the traditional way of programming to achieve the goal but it is not as elegant as using linq/lambda. I tried to use Lambda but I got stuck in how to flatten multiple rows into 1.

I have a mock DataTable for testing purpose.

```
static DataTable GetData()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Field1", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Field2", typeof(string));

    table.Rows.Add("A", "A1");
    table.Rows.Add("A", "A2");
    table.Rows.Add("B", "B1");
    table.Rows.Add("A", "A3");
    table.Rows.Add("C", "C1");
    table.Rows.Add("D", "D1");
    table.Rows.Add("A", "A5");

    return table;
}
```

My traditional way to convert it to Dictionary is:

```
    Dictionary<string, ArrayList> t = new Dictionary<string, ArrayList>();
    foreach (DataRow r in GetData().Rows)
    {
        string k = (string)r["Field1"];
        string v = (string)r["Field2"];
        if (!t.Keys.Contains(r["Field1"]))
        {
            t.Add(k, new ArrayList());
        }
        if (t.Values == null)
        {
            t[k] = new ArrayList();
        }
        t[k].Add(v);
    }
```

How do I achieve the same thing with Linq?

I have tried:

```
var res = GetData()
                     .AsEnumerable()
                     .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("Field1"))
                     .Select(grp => grp.First());
```

This only gives me the first occurrence of the item. I am stuck.
Please help.

Comment: Instead of Select, use ToDictionary and see how far you get. You'll use grp.Key and grp.ToList().

Comment: You may want to read [What's so bad about ArrayLists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17238764/215552)...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq Expression to Turn DataTable to Dictionary of <Key, List<Values>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617932/linq-expression-to-turn-datatable-to-dictionary-of-key-listvalues)

Comment: Actually you don't want to convert it to a `Dictionary`, but to a [`Lookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2).

Comment: @HereticMonkey: I know ArrayList is overkill in this simplification but in my project, the object type in the list is not string and not just 1 type. I want it to be generic and can take any type. Thank you for the warning though.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: May I ask why do I not want it to be a dictionary but look up? Is it speed related? Performance?

Comment: @user1205746 Read: [Difference between Lookup() and Dictionary(Of list())](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13362490/4934172) so you can decide what works best for you.

Comment: A lookup allows efficient search for a key, like a dictionary, but unlike a dictionary can hold multiple values per key. It seems that it's the kind of data structure that you are aiming for. It has some restrictions though. It is immutable (read-only), and the values of each key are accessible as an Enumerable<T>, not as an indexed collection (although they can be casted to IList<T>, but this is undocumented and so not future-proof).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you don't want to convert it to a Dictionary, but to a [`Lookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2). Here's an example:

```
var lookup = GetData().AsEnumerable()
    .ToLookup(r => r.Field<string>("Field1"), r => r.Field<string>("Field2"));
foreach (var grouping in lookup)
{
    Console.WriteLine(grouping.Key + ": " +  String.Join(", ", grouping));
}
```

Output:

```
A: A1, A2, A3, A5
B: B1
C: C1
D: D1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Get Data from Datatable as Dictionary without Linq/Lambda

```cs
        DataTable dataTable = GetData();
        var data = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        foreach (DataRow dataTableRow in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn tableColumn in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                dic.Add(tableColumn.ColumnName, dataTableRow[tableColumn]);
            }
            data.Add(dic);
        }
```

Comment: var data = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>(); so the object in that dictionary can be any datatype? @Qamar Zaman

Comment: Yes @SovitMaharjan

Answer (score 0):

you can get a Collection:

```
            var res = GetData()
                 .AsEnumerable()
                 .Select(grp => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(grp[0].ToString(), grp[1].ToString()));
```