# c# DataTable to dict multiple column (ex. python dataframe.to_dict("record"))

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I'm using c# DataTable.

DataTable has the following format.

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 ...
a    b    c    d    ...
aa   bb   cc   dd   ...
...  ...  ...  ...
```

And the dictionary format I want is as follows.

```
{"col1":a, "col2":b, "col3":c, "col4":d, ...}, {"col1":aa, "col2":bb, "col3":cc, "col4":dd, ...}, ...
```

How can I convert like above?

In the case of python, conversion is easily possible using the **dataframe.to_dict('record')** function.

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: can you give the C# **type declaration** of the expected dict?(above *dict* is invalid dict in my opinion)

Comment: @LeiYang Could you be more precise?

Comment: or post the expected convert function declaration(that **compiles**). then i can try to code the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simpler, less complex method like the following post suggests. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55856220/14459189